# Не работает Trigger2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал объект с sprite renderer, collider2D,Rigidbody2D.Создал Sphere collider с IsTrigger.В скрипт коллайдера вставил такой код:

```
         void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    GameObject enteredObject = other.gameObject;
    print(enteredObject.name);
    Debug.Log ("hello");
    print("hello");
}
```

}

Все объекты стоят на одной оси Z, но в консоль ничего не выводится.В чем проблема?

Comment: `Создал Sphere collider` - так в этом и проблема. работа с 2d - нужно collider2d......это же разные виды обработок....Логично, что OnTriggerEnter2D не может поймать действия от **не** 2d коллайдера

Comment: Простите, circle collider 2d

Comment: а спрайт как двигается? какой код?

Comment: объект с sprite render'ом.Монстр двигается так:                       void Update ()  {
  if  (transform.position.x >= 95) {
   speed = -speed;
  }
   if (transform.position.x <= 80) {
   speed = -speed;
   print ("Test");
  }

  transform.Translate (Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);

 }
}P.S.  за этот код не судите

Comment: Разобрался. Поставил на тригер в rigidbody2D simulated и gravity=0(чтоб не падал) и на обьект тоже поставил simulated